# Autoresize textarea in angular 2 based by content?

Tags: javascript, angular

So i have `textarea` and i want that on start have one row, and to be expanded based by content. Any suggestion how can i do that?

http://jsfiddle.net/Tw9Rj/7/

I have this fiddle but i dont want to add scroll i want to add height on textarea. Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
var s_height = document.getElementById('note').scrollHeight;
document.getElementById('note').setAttribute('style','height:'+s_height+'px');
```

Comment: I personally used [Angular Material](https://material.angular.io/components/input/api) for that. It does this automatically.

Comment: Cannot find @angular/material module

Comment: Because you have to install it, import it, and so on. Read their guides (top left corner, click on guides)